# IPsec S2S Strongswan with left subnet /32

Tags: vpn, ipsec, strongswan

I would like to know if it is possible to set up a Site to Site IPSec VPN with a VPS running strongswan.

This VPS has no private IP but only a public IP.

So my left subnet will be my public IP in /32

Is this a problem?

Will a basic configuration like this work?

```
vim /etc/sysctl.conf

net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1 
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0 
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0



Vim /etc/ipsec.conf

config setup
        charondebug="all"
        uniqueids=yes
conn S2S_IPSec
        type=tunnel
        auto=start
        keyexchange=ikev2
        authby=secret
        left=52.295.XX.12
        leftsubnet=52.295.XX.12/32
        right=232.12.XX.41
        rightsubnet=10.0.0.0/24
        ike=aes256-sha1-modp1024!
        esp=aes256-sha1!
        aggressive=no
        keyingtries=%forever
        ikelifetime=28800s
        lifetime=3600s
        dpddelay=30s
        dpdtimeout=120s
        dpdaction=restart


vim /etc/ipsec.secrets

52.295.XX.12 232.12.XX.41 : PSK "qLGLTVQOfXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXo6ac="


iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 500 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 4500 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport  500 -s 232.12.XX.41/32 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 4500 -s 232.12.XX.41/32 -j ACCEPT
```

Thanks for your help :)

Regards